# Is it possible to show a balloon tip from the system tray via Python?

Tags: python, winapi

I think I've found the relevant MSDN doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx But I'm unsure how to (or if it is possible) go about accessing such functionality via pywin32.

Comment: Try ctypes, it allows you to call arbitrary library functions easily.

Comment: QT has system tray handling (multi-platform) if you can use PyQT or PySide. You can also call the .Net API directly if using IronPython instead of cPython.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to be able to show a balloon tip through that API unless you are using IronPython.

The pywin32api is just a wrapper for the win32 c/c++ libraries. So the library you would be looking for is the [Shell_NotifyIcon function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can get at the taskbar using the win32api, but it is nontrivial. Here is an example that someone else has created to [minimize a python application to the task bar](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html).

You may also find it much easier to use something like IronPython, WxPython, PyQT, or PyGTK.